# ActionCable NoMethod Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've added simple ActionCable to my toy rails app and discovered that I'm getting

> Error: ProductsControllerTest#test_should_update_product:
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `server' for ApplicationCable:Module
>       app/controllers/products_controller.rb:53:in`block in update'
>
> ```
> app/controllers/products_controller.rb:44:in `update'
> test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:44:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
> ```

when I start my rails unit tests. It's the only time when error occurs. 
My code:

products_controller_test:

```
  test 'should update product' do
    patch product_url(@product), params: { product: @update }
    assert_redirected_to product_url(@product)
  end
```

config/application.rb

```
require 'action_cable'
```

/app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
  end
end
```

/app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
  end
end
```

/app/channels/products_channel.rb

```
class ProductsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from 'products'
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

/app/assets/javascripts/channels/products.coffee

```
App.products = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ProductsChannel",
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    $(".store #main").html(data.html)
```

/app/controllers/products_controller.rb

```
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html do
          redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully
          updated.'
        end
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }

        @products = Product.all
        ApplicationCable.server.broadcast 'products',
                                          html: render_to_string('store/index',
                                                                 layout: false)
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in products_controller.rb. You should use 'ActionCable.server.broadcast' instead of ApplicationCable.server.broadcast

Have fun!