# Undefined method `server` for ActionCable:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I am currently experiencing a problem with the implementation of ActionCable in my server.

I would like to know if you know where the problem comes from in the logs below.

I tried to require ActionCable in `application.rb` but it didn't work.

> /home/kalimink/Bureau/happer-api/config/routes.rb:3:in 'block in top (required)>': undefined method `server` for ActionCable:Module (NoMethodError)

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  mount ActionCable.server => "/cable"
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  # more routes here
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionCable NoMethod Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461917/actioncable-nomethod-error)

Comment: Not at all, i never had this problem , i edit my post to show where the error is from.

Comment: How did you try to require in application.rb? Add code, please. Did you get the same error in this case?